# How to add generic types to ndarray

Tags: numpy, types

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import ndarray

def foo() -> ndarray:

    a = np.array([1.0, 2.2, 3.3333])
    print(a)
    print(type(a))

    return a
```

When I run this through `mypy` I am getting the following error:

```
foo.py:5: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "ndarray"
```

I would like to specify the following info in the type annotation:

- The length will always be 3
- All items will be floats

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

You need to build your [ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) in this way:

```
a = np.ndarray(shape=3, dtype=float, buffer=np.array([1.0, 2.2, 3.3333]))
```

Comment: I am asking specifically about this line: `def foo() -> ndarray:`